# Correct place of the adverb never

Tags: adverbs

What is the difference between the following two sentences regarding the position of **never**?

> 1. There **never has arisen** a great man who has not been misunderstood.
> 2. There **has never arisen** a great man who has not been misunderstood.

Is there any rule regarding the position of the adverb never?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentence 2 is the "normal" way to say it.

Sentence 1 is more "artistic", and it adds an additional stress on "never".

Answer (score -1):

Only the second sentence is grammatically  correct:

[The Position of the Adverb in a Sentence](https://www.grammar.cl/Basic/Adverbs_Frequency.htm)

"An adverb of frequency goes before a main verb (except with To Be).

When we use an auxiliary verb (**have**, will, must, might, could, would, can, etc.), the adverb is placed between the auxiliary and the main verb. This is also true for to be."